# When Elm Html.Program calls subscriptions

Tags: elm

I've found a possible answer to this question in [a Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elm-discuss/7iorvKOUjJk) but I'll like to know if it's correct and add a follow-up question if it is correct.

The answer there is

> Every time the global update function in your app runs for any reason,
>   the global subscriptions object is reevaluated as well, and effect
>   managers receive the new list of current subscriptions

If any time the model is changed `subscriptions` get called what is the effect on subscriptions such as `Time.every second` taken from [Time Effect Elm Guide](https://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/effects/time.html) - is that means the timer get reset when the model changes? What if that was `Time.every minute` - if the model changes 20 seconds after it starts will it fire in `60 - 20 = 40 seconds` or will it fire in `1 minute`?

Answer (score 3):

You can check when `update` and `subscriptions` are called by adding a `Debug.log` statement to each. The `subscriptions` function is called first at the start (since the messages which will be sent to `update` may depend on it) and also after each call to `update`.

The timer interval seems to be unaffected by subsequent calls to `subscriptions`. For example, if you use the [elm clock example](http://elm-lang.org/examples/time), change the subscription to

```
Time.every (10*Time.second) Tick
```

and add a button to the view which resets the model value to 0, you will see that the tick still takes place at regular 10s intervals, no matter when you click the button.

Answer (score 1):

> TLDR; It will fire in `1 minute`, *unless you turn your subscription
>   off and on during the first minute*

Every time your `update` runs, the `subscriptions` function will run too.
The subscriptions function essentially is a list of things you want your app to subscribe to.

In the example you have a subscription that generates a `Tick` message every 60 seconds.

The behavior you may expect is:

- T= 0s: The first time `subscriptions` runs, you start your subscription to "receive `Tick` message every 60 seconds".
- T= between 0 AND 60s: As long as that particular subscription remains ON, it doesn't matter how often your `update` function runs. `subscriptions` will be run, but as long as your particular subscription to the `Tick` remains ON, things are fine.
- T= 60s: You receive a `Tick` message from your subscription, which in turn will fire `update` to be called.
- T= 60s: `subscriptions` will run again (because of previous call to `update`)

What could be interesting is what happens if the subscription to `Tick` is canceled along the way and then reinstated:

- T= 0: subscription to `Tick`
- T= 20s: suppose something changes in the model, causing subscription to `Tick` to be canceled
- T= 40s: some other change in model, causing subscription to `Tick` to be turned on again
- T= 100s: `Tick` message is fired, and passed to `update` function
- T= 100s: `subscriptions` will run again